# How to directely set a default keySpace for connecting to a Cassandra database cluster with URL format from .Net?

Tags: c#, cassandra, network-programming, datastax

I'm using `DataStax C# Driver` to connect to a `Cassandra` data base via `.Net`.

My code to assign a default `keySpace`  to `Cassandra` via specific `port` is like this:

```
Cluster Cluster = Cluster.Builder().WithPort(port).WithDefaultKeyspace(keySpace).AddContactPoint(specificIPAddress).Build();
```

I want to directely assign a default `keySpace` using `URL` format something like this:

```
Cluster Cluster = Cluster.connect("IPAdress:Port/KeySpace");
```

how can I do this using `DataStax C# Driver`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no one-liner for contact point plus keyspace.

You should use [one cluster instance per Cassandra cluster (in your case a single-node cluster) and one session per keyspace in your app lifetime](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/2.7/csharp-driver/csdFaq.html).

In your case it should be:

```
var cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint(contactPoint).Build();
var session = cluster.Connect(keyspace);
```

Remember that you can use one or more contact points. After connecting to one of the contact point, the driver will discover the rest of the nodes (if any).